# datatables java - invalid json response

Tags: java, json, datatables

I'm trying to use datatables with java and after changing the format of my json a few times I still can get datatables working

I've been through the documentation and I think the json is correct, however datatables always complains

error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response ...
```

json data:

```
{
    "recordsTotal":3,
    "recordsFiltered":3,
    "data":[
        {"id":"3385453","entityCode":"IVR","entityId":"189858","satusCode":"A","typeCode":"U1","locationCode":"B","entryDate":1193025600000},
        {"id":"54321000","entityCode":"IVR","entityId":"189858","satusCode":"A","typeCode":"O1","locationCode":"E","entryDate":1413317138380},
        {"id":"54321001","entityCode":"IVR","entityId":"189858","satusCode":"A","typeCode":"O1","locationCode":"E","entryDate":1413317138430}
    ]
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "api/documents/entity-id/189858/data-table",
            "dataType": "jsonp",
            "columns": [
                 { "data": "id" },
                 { "data": "entityCode" },
                 { "data": "entityId" },
                 { "data": "statusCode" },
                 { "data": "typeCode" },
                 { "data": "locationCode" },
                 { "data": "entryDate" }
             ]
        }
    });
});
```

html:

```
<table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>G</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: So where is the problem ... on the server side or on the client side?

Comment: @Drejc I've update my question to avoid confusion. basically upon reception of the json in datatables I get the aforementioned error: "DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response .."  so the json is invalid but i dont see what's wrong in it